# python make class iterable by returning embedded iterable

Tags: python, iterable

I have a class in python, which has an iterable as instance variable. I want to iterate the instances of the class by iterating over the embedded iterable.

I implemented this as follows:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self._iterable.__iter__()
```

I don't really feel that comfortable calling the `__iter__()` method on the iterable, as it is a special method. Is this how you would solve this problem in python or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: You might want to keep an eye on PEP 380 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) which will make this possible with ``yield from self._iterable`` (this is accepted for inclusion in 3.3).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The "best" way to way to delegate `__iter__` would be:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self._iterable)
```

Alternately, it might be worth knowing about:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for item in self._iterable:
        yield item
```

Which will let you fiddle with each item before returning it (ex, if you wanted `yield item * 2`).

And as @Lattyware mentions in the comments, PEP380 (slated for inclusion in Python 3.3) will allow:

```
def __iter__(self):
    yield from self._iterable
```

Note that it may be tempting to do something like:

```
def __init__(self, iterable):
    self.__iter__ = iterable.__iter__
```

But this *won't work*: `iter(foo)` calls the `__iter__` method on `type(foo)` directly, bypassing `foo.__iter__`. Consider, for example:

```
class SurprisingIter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__iter__ = lambda self: iter("abc")

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([1, 2, 3])
```

You would expect that `list(SurprisingIter())` would return `["a", "b", "c"]`, but it actually returns `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: There is a typo in the PEP380 variant, which I prefer. It should be `def __iter__(self): yield from self._iterable`